# Fnd the distance between the bicycles

Tags: trigonometry

From the same point two bicycles are launched at different angles. One moves at a speed of $9m / s$ and the other at $15m / s$. What is the distance between bicycles after half an hour after departure if their movement angles form $60^0$.

My attemp is:

$c^2=a^2+b^2-2ab\cos\gamma$
$c^2=9^2+15^2-2\cdot9\cdot15\cos60^0=171$

But solution in my book is 27,8km

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far  you found the square of the relative velocity. To obtain the distance you should take the square root and multiply the result by time:
$
d=\sqrt{171}\times1800\approx 23538
$ m. It is still different from the given "solution".

Comment: i dont know sir

Comment: 1km/h is it equal 5/12 m/s or no

Comment: why $13,1\cdot 1800$?

Comment: 1/2h=1800s. (and the velocities are given in m/s)

Answer (score 0):

You only calculated their distance after one second.

You need to multiply 1800s (half hour) to their speeds to get their respective distances before applying the cosine formula.

Comment: What betmen12 has calculated is the square of the distance between the 2 bicycles after 1 second. You have to find the square-root  of the value before multiplying it by 1800. To get the distance in km you have to divide it by 1000. May I ask you a question? What is the answer given in the book? Is it 27.8km or 37.8km?

Comment: in the book answer is 27,8km

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution

The distance traveled by the two bicycles after half an hour are as follows;

the slower bicycle :  $\left(9\times 30\times 60\right)/1000 = 16.2\space\rm km$

the faster bicycle :  $\left(15\times 30\times 60\right)/1000 = 27\space\rm km$

the distance between the two bicycle after half an hour: $$\left(16.2^2+27^2-2\times 16.2\times 27\times\rm cos(60)\right)^{1/2} = 23.538\space\rm km$$